# Finding data in a collection of objects where values are common to all names within the object

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a collection of objects that contain names, locations, and values.  I have a list of locations I need to compare the data to.  What I need to do is only pull the records that have names and values that are common to all the locations in my list.

So if there is no item in my objects for one of the locations, I ignore all those items.  I only want those items that are all common to my list of locations.

How would I write a linq statement to pull that out?  Or even a lambda statement would work.  I really don't want to loop through all the records multiple times to find the common records.

Comment: You should add the `linq` tag to this question. Also LINQ was added in C# 3.5, so you should replace the `c#3.0` tag with `c#`. Not to be nitpicking, but for future reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I assume correctly you have an object that has name, location and value as properties and you want to get the ones from a collection with the same location.

Say you have the following object

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string name{set;get;}
    public string location{set;get;}
    public string value{set;get}
}
```

and you have a Collection of those objects like `IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects;`

You can search through this collection to get the object with the same location:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> results = myObjects.Where(mo => mo.location.Contains("targetLocation"));
```

or you can say:

```
var results = from o in myObjects 
              where o.location.Contains("something") 
              select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets all the objects which's location is in the list of locations:

```
dataObjects.Where(o => locations.Any(l => l == o.Location));
```

If you need more complex comparisons, you should post the structure of the classes involved, so we can give you a more accurate answer.